# Matsubara sum with a small phase

Tags: statistical-mechanics, path-integral, integration, regularization, quantum-statistics

in the text book by Altland and Simons (Condensed Matter Fiel Theory) in chapter 4, summation over Matsubara frequencies is explained. The basic idea is to choose an auxiliary function and multiply it to the expression in the sum such that one gets the original function back with the residue theorem. On page 171/172 it says under note 13 that the particle number $N$
$$
N\approx T\sum_n \frac{1}{-i\omega_n+\xi_a}
$$
is an approximation. However, the exact result is obtained if one keeps the infinitesimal phase $\exp(-i\omega_n\delta)$ from the discretization scheme to construct the path integral. The exact result would then be
$$
N = T\sum_n \frac{1}{-i\omega_n e^{-i\omega_n\delta}+\xi_a}\, .
$$
I have two questions regarding that comment 13:

1. In the comment it says, sums of the type
   $\sum_n \frac{1}{i\omega_n - \xi_a}$ are ill-convergent. How are we then able to calculate its value with the residue theorem at all? If we find a result, then it must be well defined and the whole discussion above is unnecessary...
2. If we have a well-defined sum (not sure why it is well-defined)
   $$
   \sum_n \frac{e^{-i\omega_n\delta}}{-i\omega_n e^{-i\omega_n\delta}+\xi_a}
   $$
   How can we calculate it while keeping the phase $e^{-i\omega_n\delta}$? (The roots are Lambert $W$ functions, i.e., product logarithm, and they are imaginary?)

Thanks in advance.